# android java add edit contacts google accounts

Tags: java, android, contacts, google-contacts-api

I want to access (add, edit) contacts of Google accounts on an android device. I'm using Android Studio.
I've found couple posts on  http://stackoverflow.com:

[Android - sync contact add programatically to google account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821781/android-sync-contact-add-programatically-to-google-account)

[Xml model for adding contact to google contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090897/xml-model-for-adding-contact-to-google-contacts)

However, first mentions problem and have no answer, second has only some parts of code and both do not show how to choose account if there are sereral on a device.

I foresee it could be considered broad question, however, if OK, please advice how to do my task with less code and setup (e.g. Maven or jar libraries or else) and with specific code samples - via Google API or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off delegating this kind of work to the system, using Intents. You can have a look at how Google recommends to do it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html)

I hope this helps!